# Bridge mode question

Tags: encryption

İ have an outdoor in my shop and distributing my network to customers using mac filtering opition.. 
 one of my neighboor got a weak signal....so, he bought a wirelss repeater to recieve a better signal
 to use it on his mobile.
so should i put his repater mac or İ must establish a bridge point to point connection? 
As İ do not want him to spread my network without my permission.
Please give me your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically anyone who is capable of connecting to your network is capable of sharing it without your permission.  Any device connected to your network can create a private LAN within the original LAN and share the Internet connection by allowing devices to correct to the new, inner LAN.  This is sometimes known as a double-NAT.  If the repeater is configured this way, then from your point of view there will only be one additional device on the network (the repeater) no matter how many people connect to the repeater.

Fortunately, most off-the-shelf consumer repeaters do not normally work this way; instead of creating a new LAN the repeater will extend (bridge) the original LAN, so anyone who connects to the repeater will be connected to your main network and thus be subjected to MAC filtering.  Even so, your best bet would be to talk to your neighbor to make sure the repeater is extending your LAN rather than creating a new one.

You should also be aware that MAC authentication is a very weak method of wireless security.  All devices connected to a wireless network broadcast their MAC addresses in plaintext, so it's trivial to listen for them and then spoof the MAC address of a valid client.  If MAC authentication is your sole method of protection, you should really consider giving your customers WPA2 keys instead. If you have the necessary equipment to do WPA2-Enterprise you can even give each customer a distinct login and password.